# Which is a better practice - global import or local import

Tags: python, django, import

I am developing an app in django and I had a doubt if importing a library at the global level has any impact over the memory or performance than importing at the local ( per-function) level. If it is imported per function or view, the modules that are needed alone are imported saving space right? Or are there any negatives in doing so?

Comment: I don't know much about django, but if multiple functions needs to import the same module, wouldn't it be a waste to import it in each function?

Comment: @aIKid: But I think the server side execution executes the functions only on the client's request. So won't it be a waste of memory to import all? That is my question

Comment: If the module is imported once, it will be in memory from then on. Might as well do so immediately, if the size of your modules is a memory problem then you have a very atypical situation.

Comment: What if multiple programs run on the server? Still they will be in the memory?

Comment: @alKid: it's not a (significant) waste of time, since subsequent imports after the first will find the module in `sys.modules` very quickly. It might be a waste of typing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You surely must have noticed that almost all Python code does the imports at the top of the file. There's a reason for that: the overhead of importing is minimal, and the likelihood is that you will be importing the code at some point during the process lifetime anyway, so you may as well get it out of the way.

The only good reason to import at function level is to avoid circular dependencies.

**Edit** Your comments indicate you haven't understood how web apps generally work, at least in Python. They don't start a new process for each request and import the code from scratch. Rather, the server instantiates processes as required, and each one serves many requests until it is finally killed. So again it is likely that during that lifetime, all the imports will end up being needed.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that imports at the top of the file, and [the order in which they should be written](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id16) are both mentioned in PEP8.

Comment: Now I get it.. Thanks

Comment: Very close to what I was going to say. I import evrything at the top, except the modules which would otherwise create circular dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

### Import Statement Overhead

From [Python Performance Tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead):

> It's often useful to place them inside functions to restrict their visibility and/or reduce initial startup time. Although Python's interpreter is optimized to not import the same module multiple times, repeatedly executing an import statement can seriously affect performance in some circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

When the script is run, it will store the modules in memory, i'm sure you understand that.

If you're importing on a local scope, the module will be imported each time the client calls the function. But if the module is imported at a global level, there will be no need for that!

So, in this case: global import wins.

Comment: But if multiple programs run on the server? There is no problem still?

Comment: To be preceise, the module will be imported once (sometimes by other functions or global imports), all subsequent calls to import will result in `sys.modules` lookup.

Comment: Multiple programs? I can't see any relation with that here.. But either it's imported locally or globally, separate process has their own place in memory. Script `a` will have their modules, and script `b` will have their own place to store the modules.