# Do packages at the top of a module get imported when we are only calling a function from that module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a module `foo.py`, which I am importing in my file `main.py`, I have `imports` at the top of `foo.py` such as `import numpy as np`, etc. 
Now, if I'm only calling a certain function `fun(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, do the `imports` at the top of `foo.py` take place or do I have to add the `imports` inside the function definition of `fun`?

Also, does `from foo import fun` make a difference then `import foo` in this regard?

**File `foo.py` (to be imported)**

```
import numpy as np

def fun(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    x = np.argsort(arg1)
    return x
```

**File `main.py`**

```
import foo

call = fun([2, 34, 0, -1], 4, 5])
```

Or should I go with this in `foo.py`?

```
def fun(arg1, arg2, arg3):
   import numpy as np
   x = np.argsort(arg1)
   return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the module is loaded for the first time, all the lines in it are run. `import`s, `def`s, regular assignments, etc. All these lines initialize a namespace that is the module object. The namespace of `foo` will have a variable `np` that points to the loaded numpy module, and a variable `fun` that points to your function object.

Functions are first class objects in python. In particular, they have a [`__globals__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) (look under "Callable Types" in the linked docs) attribute, which points to the namespace of the module they were defined in. No matter what you do to the reference of `foo.fun`, the name`np` will be available in the function until you delete it from `foo` itself.

It is not recommended that you import anything inside your function, unless you have good reason to do so, like avoiding a global name. When you `import` a module, the interpreter will first look into `sys.modules`. If it is found, the `import` will not take much longer than a lookup into the global dictionary. However, if the module hasn't been loaded yet, it will be right there and then. You may not want to incur that overhead at an arbitrary point in your program, especially one that may be time-sensitive.

As far as import form, the differences are mostly aesthetic, but they do have practical consequences as well. `from foo import fun` creates a name `fun` in your namespace, referring directly to the function object of interest. It contaminates your local namespace with an extra name, but saves you a lookup through `foo`'s namespace dictionary every time you access the function. `import foo`, on the other hand, keeps everything bundled nicely since you have to call `foo.fun`, but that requires an extra lookup.

**TL;DR**

You should put all your imports at the top of your file. It doesn't really matter how you do it.

Comment: What amount of overhead will be there for imports from function like `import numpy as np`and lookups in the namespace dictionary for the function object when using `import foo`, calling foo.fun.

Comment: @aspiring1. The first time numpy is loaded, it will load a whole bunch of shared libraries (.so or .dll), and all the python modules that provide support for the main namespace. This is fast in human time: a small fraction of a second, but it's very lengthy in terms of program time. The second import will just be doing the equivalent of `np = sys.modules['numpy']`. This is significant. The difference between `foo.fun()` and `fun()` is likely never going to be noticed, which is why I said the difference is primarily aesthetic there.

Answer (score 4):

No you don't need to import it again inside `fun`. You can test this out, your code should work even if your import `numpy` only once at the top of `foo.py`.

The two ways don't make any difference except that if you import as `import foo` you have to refer to `fun` as `foo.fun`. If you do `from foo import fun` instead, you can just use `fun`.

When you import a module, python will execute all the statements in the module file. So, when you import foo, in either of the above two ways, it will run `import numpy as np` and update the private symbol table for `foo`. All statements, functions defined inside `foo` can use symbols in this table without any qualification. In your case, `fun` will have access to `numpy` as `np`.

What happens to `numpy` import itself is more interesting.

**Case 1**

`from foo import fun`

You are only importing `fun` nothing else. Whatever code in `fun` will run because of the above reasons, but `np` itself will be invisible to code in `main`.

**Case 2**

`import foo`

Here you will refer to `fun` as `foo.fun` like I said before, but `np` can also be used as `foo.np` but this is absolutely not recommended.

It's always best to import modules again if you are going to use them in the current file, don't rely on indirect imports from other files. Since, python caches imports you needn't worry about performance or circular imports.

Read about the [import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache) to understand all this fully.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: If the packages from the module are also imported, then there shouldn't be any problem when I don't `import numpy as np` and **after the call to fun, define another variable x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])**, but I tried such an example and it doesn't work? I get  `print(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
NameError: name 'np' is not defined `

Comment: @aspiring1 I understand where your question is coming from, see my edited answer that explains why you have to `import numpy` again in `main.py`

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to import it again inside function fun().

For further, please check this
[Which is a better practice - global import or local import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346189/which-is-a-better-practice-global-import-or-local-import)